# Issues Adjusting Time format in excel

Tags: excel, date, time, pivot

I am using Excel and I am having issues with the order of my dates and times being arranged properly in a pivot chart.

The format is 6/1/2017  9:07:02 AM and so on for a log file.

When the pivot table is set up it will put 10am and 11am and 12am before 2pm and 9 am. since it goes in order it believes 1 in 10 and 1 in 11 and 1 in 12 comes before 2 and 9.

I need to adjust these times to say like 6/1/2017  09:07:02 AM with the leading zero to eliminate these issues. This is a massive log file so it cannot be done by hand. Suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to format the dates as a date format? Don't use general format.

Comment: Yeah but I am using excel 2007 and when I do this I only get general, text, date, no time option. So it is stored as text which I believe is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the text to a date/time index and plot that instead:

```
=DATEVALUE(LEFT(A1,10))+TIMEVALUE(MID(A1,12,8))+IF(RIGHT(A1,2)="PM",0.5,)
```